# UseCompatibleTextRendering property not created by designer when it is set to false

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I do not wish to use compatible text rendering, but I do not wish to use

```
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
```

Naturally, I thought all I had to do was set each label's UseCompatibleTextRendering property to false.  The Forms Designer, however, apparently only generates code to set the property if UseCompatibleTextRendering is set to true.

No problem, I thought, that must mean that UseCompatibleTextRendering is initialized to false by default.  Yet when I start up my form, lo and behold, I see ugly CompatibleTextRendering. So, a question:

1) Why on earth isn't the designer adding code for UseCompatibleTextRendering when I set it to false and it *is* when I set it to true, if the default is true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The designer does not add code for setting `UseCompatibleTextRendering` to `false`, because `false` is the default value.

So, why do the controls use compatible text rendering by default, if the default value of the property is `false`, that seems to be... odd? Well, the `Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault` method assigns the given value to a static field in the Control class, and the static constructor of the Control class initializes this field to `true`.

So, removing the line `Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);` will cause the application to use compatible text rendering, contrary to what you might think based on the default value of the `UseCompatibleTextRendering` property.

The only reasonable solution that I can see is to simply leave the automatically generated call to `Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault` where it is.

Comment: Thanks.  Why Control.UseCompatibleTextRenderingDefault is initialized to true baffles me.

Answer (score 3):

The problem occured in an **Com-Interop-DLL** I wrote for use within *Microsoft Excel*.

The DLL is written in *VB.NET* and contains a Form that is shown from within *Excel*.

Now, the *Excel.Application* sets the `UseCompatibleTextRendering` to `true` by default. Therefore all labels and buttons of the form render poorly if the DLL is embedded in *Excel* (GDI+-Graphics-Class) but perfectly right from within any *.Net-Windows Application*.

To correct this, I had to loop over all labels and buttons and set the `UseCompatibleTextRendering` to `false` on `Form.Load` event.
I found no way to use the `SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault` neither within the DLL nor within Excel.

Comment: Edit: The same happens if You create a Console Application and reference the DLL to show a windows form.

Comment: There is a note that you can't change it parent application sets it (for a first WinForm) here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.setcompatibletextrenderingdefault?view=net-5.0

Exceptions
InvalidOperationException
You can only call this method before the first window is created by your Windows Forms application.